# Postfix fail sending to any external domain

Tags: postfix, smtp, courier

I have a problem :(
When we try to send a mail to external demain by SMTP and Postfix + Courier+ Webmin, In the logs i got an error :

```
Sep 18 10:57:34 MyDomain postfix/error[26300]: 275FF1EEC9B: to=<user@Other.example.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

But when the email is sent to internal accounts no problems.

My main.cf is:

```
#See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job. append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key smtpd_use_tls = no smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client. myhostname = domain.net alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases myorigin = /etc/mailname mydestination = domain.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain mynetworks =
127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 mailbox_command = mailbox_size_limit = 0 recipient_delimiter = + inet_interfaces = all inet_protocols = all smtpd_sasl_local_domain = smtpd_sasl_auth_enable
= yes broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders permit_sasl_authenticated permit_inet_interfaces reject_unauth_destination smtp_use_tls = no smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1 smtpd_tls_received_header = yes smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom home_mailbox = Maildir/

smtpd_helo_required = yes smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                          permit_sasl_authenticated,
                          reject_unauth_pipelining,
                          reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                          reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                          reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                          reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                          reject_unauth_destination,
                          reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
                          reject_rbl_client blackholes.wirehub.net,
                          reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
                          permit content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024 receive_override_options = no_address_mappings html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html message_size_limit = 30720000 virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf virtual_alias_domains
= virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf virtual_mailbox_maps
= proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail virtual_uid_maps = static:5000 virtual_gid_maps = static:5000 smtpd_tls_security_level = may transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
#relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf virtual_create_maildirsize = yes virtual_maildir_extended = yes virtual_mailbox_limit_inbox = yes virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes virtual_maildir_limit_message = "The user you are trying to reach is over quota." virtual_overquota_bounce = yes proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
# smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1 maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1 virtual_transport = maildrop header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks

## local ### disable_vrfy_command = yes smtpd_banner = $myhostname smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_inet_interfaces /
```

In Webmin in the "SMTP Authentication And Encryption" seccion, when we try uncheck "Reject email to other domains" option we get another failed and this in  the log:

> fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one
>   working instance of:check_relay_domains reject_unauth_destination
>   reject defer defer_if_permit

So, we have try add one  of these parameters (check_relay_domains reject_unauth_destination reject defer defer_if_permit
) in smtpd_recipient_restrictions, but it has not solved.

The users can send emails but the server not delivery then (are all in the queue).

This is my master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
1025      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission      inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticat$
smtps   inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o mi$
628     inet    n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
   -o content_filter=
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
qmgr    fifo    n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp    unix    -       -       -       -       -       smtp When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -w90 -d vmail ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop} ${sender}
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -w90 -d ${recipient} ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop} ${sender}
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

amavis unix -      -       n     -       2  smtp
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       -     -       -  smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
    -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
```

Can you please help me?.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Post your `master.cf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's typo on your actual config or not, but you may need to split this line on `master.cf`

```
smtp    unix    -       -       -       -       -       smtp When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
```

into

```
smtp    unix    -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
```

Comment: masegaloeh , this line was part of the problem. Thank you